# Method (SimpleCursorAdapter) still deprecated after imports (supported library)

Tags: android

I want to use SimpleCursorAdapter on API 8. Therefore i already installed the support library and imported correctly, but Eclipse still does complain that the method is deprecated. Code below.

```
package com.example.somedb;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.ContactsContract;
import android.support.v4.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Cursor myCursor = getContacts();
        ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,
                android.R.layout.two_line_list_item,
                myCursor,
                new String[] { ContactsContract.Contacts._ID,
                ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME },
                new int[] { android.R.id.text1, android.R.id.text2 });
    }

    private Cursor getContacts() {
        //do something
    }
}
```

PS: I don't know how to format the code correctly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eclipse is warning you against using a method that has been marked as deprecated. Using deprecated methods is not recommended, so you should find another solution for what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: okay, i thought i could resolve it by using support library. thx